# Using python to parse verilog inputs

Tags: python, regex, parsing, verilog

I have a project where I need to parse information from some verilog files. The issue right now is that the files have various styles of inputs. For example, some are explicitly declared like so:

```
input clk, reset, enable;
input clk;
```

where the code looks like

```
module name (a,b,c,d, etc);
```

and the inputs and outputs are declared explicitly. However, some of the code also has declarations like so:

```
module name (
  input a,
  input b)
```

etc. So the way I have my python regex right now is:

```
input_mod = re.search(r'.*?\binput\b(.*?\S+),|;', line) 
inputs.append(input_mod.group(1))
```

where line is just each line of the document, and inputs is a list. So I think this handles the latter example and part of the first example, but I have no idea how to have it pick up the one where both commas and semicolons are included. Any help?

Comment: Haha yeah, it's definitely tempting. The reason I didn't initially do anything with that is because I'm just interning at a company, and they told me to try to do it in python, so I was just going to go with that.

Comment: True haha.  Not very python savvy so I need a lot of hand holding. Yeah, maybe I'll just have to ask my boss and see if we can just use the perl script or go back to doxygen.

Comment: Instead of using regular expressions, which always are somewhat rigid, you could implement a parser with [PyParsing](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). It takes some reading, but ultimately it will be much more flexible, because you can really implement the Verilog syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.search(r'.*?\binput\b(.*?\S+)[,;]', line)
```